# Using Json1 Extension with sqlite3

Tags: command-line, extension, json, sqlite3

The docs says, that The json1 extension is a loadable extension for sqlite3, and the loadable extensions need to be compiled as shared libraries ([source](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html)).

I searched a lot and I don't know how to enable them. I found that

- the compiled shared libraries might be provided by [libsqlite3-mod-impexp](https://packages.debian.org/sid/libsqlite3-mod-impexp)
- many article tells how to install `libsqlite3-mod-impexp` (just `apt install` actually), but none mentioned what's next, to enable the loadable extension, and use it.

Any detailed steps, and sample verification commands appreciated.

I need to use the json1 extension for sqlite3, i.e. using json in where clauses when invoking `sqlite3` command from command line.

Answer (score 2):

No, `libsqlite3-mod-impexp` is not necessary, thus no need to do  `apt install libsqlite3-mod-impexp`:

```
$ sqlite3 
SQLite version 3.11.0 2016-02-15 17:29:24
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.

sqlite> SELECT json_extract('{"a":2,"c":[4,5,{"f":7}]}', '$');
{"a":2,"c":[4,5,{"f":7}]}

$ dpkg -l | grep sqlite3
ii  libsqlite3-0:a 3.11.0-1ubun amd64        SQLite 3 shared library
ii  sqlite3        3.11.0-1ubun amd64        Command line interface for SQLite
```